# Insertar datos en un input o textarea mediante una url

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

Quiero que cuando un usuario añada en una url un texto en específico, el input de la web lo detecte y lo añada como lo tiene twitter, y si el input no detecta nada en la url este mismo se muestre vacío.

Unos ejemplos de cómo lo usa twitter:

`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hola`
`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://es.stackoverflow.com`

Un ejemplo de cómo lo quiero usar:
`https://miweb.com/intent/post?text=hola`

Este es mi formulario

```
<html>
    <head>
        <titile>Post</titile>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/post.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="post">
            <input type="sumbit" value="enviar" name="sumbit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

y este es mi script que lo uso en mi archivo home

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');//$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
$av = $_SESSION['av'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  $post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : "null";
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=;charset=utf8mb4',"","");
  //$conexion->set_charset('utf8mb4');
  
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  $video = $_POST['video'];
  //$imageBase64 = base64_encode($image);

  $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO post(usuario, cuerpo,avatar,image,video,time_date_post) VALUES (:username,:post,:avatar,:image,:video,:time_date_post)");

  $statement->bindParam(':username', $user);
  $statement->bindParam(':post', $post);
  $statement->bindParam(':avatar', $av);
  $statement->bindParam(':image', $image);
  $statement->bindParam(':video', $video);
  $statement->bindParam(':time_date_post', $date);
  $statement->execute();
}

header("Location: /");

 ?>
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con php o con javascript?

Comment: Para hacer lo que requerieres debes hacer uso del método GET, en php se utiliza facilmente, unicamente escribes lo siguiente $_GET['text'] y recupera el valor de la variable que tienes declarada en la url

Comment: @GreedSource pero no me lanzaría error si el PHP no detecta el GET[text];? Lo que quiero es que sea funcional tanto con el get mediante la url y sin el uso del get ej php.php?text=hola (con get) php.php (muestra el input vacío en el cual el usuario puede escribir lo que guste

Comment: Con un IF puedes controlar si entra el $_GET o no. Si entra lo muestras si no entra no. `if(isset($_GET['text'])) ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter lo hace por variable GET de PHP, para hacerlo simplemente debes tomar el nombre de la variable que se esta enviando por url, en el caso de twitter es text asi que se recibe $_GET['text']...

suponiendo que tienes un input...

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="" placeholder="Text"/>
```

Esto seria lo que debes implementar

```
<?php
$text = $_GET['text'];
?>

<input type="text" name="text" <?php if(isset($_GET['text']) && $_GET['text']!="") echo "value='".$text."'"; ?> placeholder="Text"/>
```

Simplemente ahora debes ingresar a tu sitio de esta forma: http://tudominio.com/?text=Hola

si el codigo no esta en el index.php de la raiz de tu web deberias ir al archivo... ejemplo

```
http://tudominio.com/agregarTexto.php?text=Hola
```

y si utilizas urls amigables seria lo mismo... Ej:

```
http://tudominio.com/agregarTexto/?text=Hola
```

si configuras para tomar una variable GET en el htaccess seria:

```
http://tudominio.com/agregarTexto/text/hola
```

o simplemente

```
http://tudominio.com/agregarTexto/hola
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres hacerlo con javascript, puedes usar URLSearchParams:

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log( urlParams.get('text') );
```

O definir una función para que lea el parámetro en la URL:

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

console.log( getUrlParameter('text') );
```

Fuente (en inglés): https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript